# How can I make a MANDATORY form field in Microsoft 2010 with VBA?

Tags: forms, vba, ms-word, word-2010

I'm really new to VBA but I'm learning quick. I need some help with making mandatory form fields in Microsoft Word. The user should not be able to Save or Save & Send the document without filling in all of the mandatory form fields.

I found the below code online:

```
Sub MustFillIn()
    If ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text1").Result = "" Then
        Do
            sInFld = InputBox("This field must be filled in, fill in below.")
        Loop While sInFld = ""
        ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text1").Result = sInFld
    End If
End Sub
```

But I do not know how to rename the field in Microsoft Word. So for example, for my first form field, it should be called "FirstName" instead of "Text 1". How do I name the form field in Microsoft Word 2010?

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Comment: If you right click the ActiveX Control / Form field > Select Properties > You can change the bookmark name. But when I try and change it with the code, the macros does not run on exit. I can't make it work. Can anyone help me? You can see what I'm talking about here: http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/master_your_formfields.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use the control's tag property to do this.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg605189(v=office.14).aspx).  This is for Word 2010, but newer versions should work the same.

Comment: Nothing about a content control tag - or in the link you posted - has anything to do with saving a document, let alone a document using formfields.